# How to add user input permanently to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, file, input, raspberry-pi, fwrite

```
teams ={ 
    "BARCELONA": "10",
    "ITALY":"11",
    "SPAIN":"9.5"
    }
print()
print("****************************")
print("GROUP GOALS RANKING")
print("****************************")
print(list(teams.keys()))
print("****************************")
name=input("Which team you are interested in:",)
print()
print("Team of {} get {} goals".format(name, teams[name]))
print("****************************")
print()
new=input("which team do you want to add to the ranking? ",)
rating=input("How much goals get? "+ new + "? ")
teams[new] = float(rating)
print()
print("****************************")
print(list(teams.keys()))
print()
print("Ranking updated, bye")
```

My question is: how to update this script so that when the script is restarted, the dictionary would be with a new entry? how to use user input and append function to add new team to dictionary for ever? ;] my english isnt perfect ;]

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: i have tried update function, writing to file and now ive started thinking about append functon, but better to ask someone smarter than i

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the dictionary in a file (or a database), otherwise it will be lost as soon as the program terminates

Comment: i think it will be more complicated, cuz i dont know how to make the same when dictionary will be in file or db

Comment: function append will not work? if i add at the end of script one line to replace the dictionary content with an additional entry?

Comment: Nope, the dictionary is stored in memory and when the program terminates the space used is then used by other programs. Unless you store it in a file or a database, there is no way you can keep it's values